# Select _Key_ in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I have this model

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Question(db.Model):
    Qtitle = db.StringProperty()

Q= FirstModel(Qtitle="Who is the most handsome actor?")
Q.put()
```

Then I run this GQL query:

```
query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM FirstModel Qtitle='Who is the most handsome actor?' ")
results = query.fetch(10)

for result in results:
   print result
```

But got error!

Comment: "Got error" - what error? Show us your stacktrace, don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1):

I see two errors:

1. Model class name is `Question` and not `FirstModel`.
2. You missed the `WHERE` clause in your query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this , or something like that

from google.appengine.ext import db

    class Question(db.Model):
        Qtitle = db.StringProperty()

    Q= Question(Qtitle="Who is the most handsome actor?")
    Q.put()

    query = db.GqlQuery('SELECT __key__ FROM Question where Qtitle = :qes' , qes='Who is the most handsome actor?').fetch(1)
                  for result in query
                    print result
```